# how to get description on column have multiple id in array to get the detail id mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-concat

I have a table profile look like this

table_1

| reg_id | reg_name | reg_colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2,3 |
| 2 | Doe | 1,3 |
| 3 | Jane |  |

---

table_2

| id_colour | colour | reg_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | black | 2,3 |
| 2 | white | 1,3 |
| 3 | green |  |

---

i want to join those column reg_colour in table 1 with id_color and the table should appear like this

| reg_id | reg_name | name_colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | white,green |
| 2 | Doe | black,green |
| 3 | Jane |  |

---

SELECT req_id,req_name,GROUP_CONCAT(colour SEPARATOR ', ') as 'name_colour'
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id_colour  = table_1.reg_colour

not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT table_1.reg_id, table_1.reg_name, GROUP_CONCAT(table_2.colour SEPARATOR ', 
') as 'name_colour'
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON FIND_IN_SET(table_2.id_colour, table_1.reg_colour)
GROUP BY table_1.reg_id, table_1.reg_name;
```